# MySQL fails to add a foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, django-south, database-migration

I added a table 'GameRatings' in the Django model and migrated using South. The table has a one-one relationship with a table called 'Game'.

The migration fails with the following error message:

> 2014-01-07 10:51:15,026] (0.505) CREATE TABLE
>   `app_gameratingsmodel` (`game_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL
>   PRIMARY KEY, `averageRating` double precision NOT NULL, `numRatings`
>   integer NOT NULL); args=[]
>
> [2014-01-07 10:51:15,650] (0.294) ALTER
>   TABLE `app_gameratingsmodel` ADD CONSTRAINT
>   `game_id_refs_gameID_fe5d3728` FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES
>   `app_gamemodel` (`gameID`);; args=[]
>
> FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE
>   `app_gameratingsmodel` ADD CONSTRAINT
>   `game_id_refs_gameID_fe5d3728` 
>   FOREIGN KEY (`game_id`) REFERENCES
>   `app_gamemodel` (`gameID`);
>
> The error was: (1822, "Failed to
>   add the foreign key constaint. Missing index for constraint
>   'game_id_refs_gameID_fe5d3728' in the referenced table
>   'app_gamemodel'")

I don't understand what index is MySQL talking about. Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python version: 2.7.2

Answer (score 3):

This occures often when you try reference two columns with different data type (e.g. VARCHAR to INT or even INT to UINT!). I always forget to check the unsigned marker in Workbench :)

Comment: I had the same problem, your answer saved me. Thank you =)

Answer (score 2):

You probably have no UNIQUE constraint on app_gamemodel.gameID. A UNIQUE (or PRIMARY KEY, which is pretty much the same) is needed for a database to be able to establish a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Thanks mjl but that isn't the case. I am digging into the CREATE statements of these two tables and realise that they have different character sets. So even though the datatype is varchar(32), the two fields do not have the same data type.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured. It turns out that there was a charset mismatch between the columns for both tables.

The charset was utf8 for the GameTable where as the new one was being created with charset latin since that was the DB's default charset. :)